Cpack multi-config not working with multi-config generator
I created very simple project as follows:
├── build
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── main.cpp

# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(MyApp)
add_executable(my_app main.cpp)

install(TARGETS my_app DESTINATION bin)

set(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME MyProj)
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_INSTALL_DIRECTORY ${CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME})
set(CPACK_VERBATIM_VARIABLES TRUE)

include(CPack)

You can think main.cpp as empty file. Here is how i selet generator and build the project.
$ cd build
$ cmake -G "Ninja Multi-Config" ..
$ cmake --build .   # <<===== It is working
$ cmake --build . --config Release  # <<===== It is working

$ cpack -G "TGZ"  # <<===== It is working
$ cpack -G "TGZ" --config Release --verbose # <<===== It is NOT working

The first cpack command(cpack -G "TGZ") works as expected. It creates the package files in
tar.gz format. But second cpack command gives below error:
CPack: Enable Verbose
CPack Verbose: Read CPack config file: Release
CPack Verbose: Read CPack configuration file: .../build/Release
CPack Error: Problem reading CPack config file: ".../build/Release"


For select project configuration to be packed with cpack use -C option. Meaning of option --config is different: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cpack.1.html#cmdoption-cpack-config
